# Why can I not write a negative number in math mode LaTex?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write in the middle of the page:

"y = -3x + 5",

but if I type

```
$$ y = -3x + 5$$,
```

I get the error that I'm missing a number, and it is assumed to be zero, but the compiler will not write my file.

I've seen answers to this where it is suggested to use "$-$3x", but I'm already in double dollar signs.  Is there any way around this? Is there a package I should be using? Or will I actually have to change the exam question because I can't get the negative symbol to work in Latex?

Here is what I have:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{exam}
  \usepackage{geometry}                
  \geometry{
   a4paper,
   total={170mm,257mm},
   left=20mm,
   top=20mm,
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \newcommand{\VecN}{\overset{\rightharpoonup}}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{tabto} 
 \usepackage{pstricks-add}

 \begin{document}
  Exam 2 Review\\
  For 1 to 4, find an equation for the line described in each problem.
     \begin{questions}
      \question A line that is parallel to the line
            $$y = -3x+5$$
       and goes through $(6,7)$
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example, starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`, plus ideally the _exact_ text you get as an error.

Comment: Unless you are using plainTeX, use `\begin{equation}…\end{equation}` and the `amsmath` package. You have to provide more code before anyone can help, missing number points to something else and not a minus sign.

Comment: If I add the missing `}` to your `\geometry` set up I have no issues with the example: are you sure you get the error with with that input _exactly_?

Comment: I copied and pasted that too hurriedly into the textbox.  I made sure it was fixed, ran it, and recevied: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.81 \question A
                line that is parallel to the line $$y= -3x+5$$ and goes through $(6,7)$

Comment: No pleas show the error you get _from the posted code_. the error message you show in comments is on line 81 and the posted code does not have 81 lines. So that error comes from a different document.

Comment: Line 81 is: "\question A line that is parallel to the line" .  I just ran it again, and I received the same message about a different line, even though I haven't changed anything.  It reads, "! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> \relax l.96 \question t he line that goes through $(2,6)$ and $(-1,2)$".  Line 96 of my code is "\question the line that goes through $(2,6)$ and $(-1,2)$".

Comment: I am voting to close this question, as the error is in some code not supplied and not described. The question as it is now is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You never close the argument for `\geometry`. After that it compiles fine. I don't see what the problem is with the `-3`? Notice that the `-` is close to the `3` while the `+` has space between the left and right side since it's acting as a binary operator. Also use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX.

Comment: I fixed that. Nothing changed.

Comment: What, exactly, is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

This code is compiling just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$y = -3x+5$$
\end{document}
```

`\begin{equation}…\end{equation}` is preferred over `$$…$$`.

`$-$3x` is horrible, as the minus will be in math mode, and then continued with `3x` in text mode.

P.S. The code you added is not minimal. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: When I run what you've written, it compiles.  When I run what I wrote in the question, it compiles as well.  But my own code does not.  I don't know what from my code I should include/address.

Comment: @bloomers: You need to study how to make a MWE(Minimal Working Example) - then you will find your error.